How to save a block with overflow-y in html2pdf.js
I have a block.
<div  class="container"> 
<div  class="words-wrapper"> 
content
</div>
</div>

and such styles
.words-wrapper {
    max-height: 750px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

My settings for html2pdf
const element = document.querySelector('.container')
    const opt = {
                margin: 0.5,
                filename: `${pageTitle.value}.pdf`,
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' },
                pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy'] },
    }

Also I add settings for printing
@media print {
    .words-wrapper {
        max-height: none !important;
        overflow-y: visible !important;
    }
}

Therefore, a block with a scroll.
When printing through a browser, all pages are displayed.
But through html2pdf, it only generates the visible part of the content.
I tried adding styles to this block before forming, but it didn't help.
const wordsWrapper = document.querySelector('.words-wrapper')
        wordsWrapper.style.maxHeight = 'none!important'
        wordsWrapper.style.overflowY = 'visible!important'

